# How to restrict display of array to only 8?

Tags: jquery, arrays, haml

I am using jquery and haml to implement my application. I am displaying a list of avatars but want to restrict the number to be max 8.

```
<% $.each(question.friends, function(i, e){ %>
<% if (typeof(e) !== 'undefined') { %>
%a{href: "/<%= e.nickname %>", rel: "tooltip", title: "<%= e.nickname %>"}
  %img{src: "<%= e.avatar_url%>"}
<% } %>
<% }); %>
```

How can I update the code above to ensure only 8 is displayed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`i` is the index, so just make sure it's less than 8:

```
if (typeof(e) !== 'undefined' && i < 8)
```

Or, if `question.friends` is an array, `slice` it to a maximum of 8 elements:

```
$.each(question.friends.slice(0, 8), function(i, e) {
```

Comment: May be it should be `i == 8`, since he wants only 8

Comment: @Starx: No, that will only include the ninth element. The OP wants to limit the number of results displayed to 8. (Or at least, that's what I understood out of that.)

Comment: My bad, just misunderstood the question